# How can I print multiple things in a row with using only fork() and if?

Tags: c, if-statement, printing, fork

after hours of searching I ended up here. Here's my problem:

I have an exercise I need to do.The code given is this:

```
int main(){
int x,y,z....;
//

fill the gap

//
printf("A");
//

fill the gap

//
printf("B");
return(0);
}
```

I must print exactly "AAAAABBB" with using **ONLY** fork(),if and exit().
(no "wait", no multiple "printf", no "sleep". no "for")

How could I do it? I have tested it in online IDEs but I just cant print them in this exact way. The output is always confusing (AABBBAA, ABABABAA etc.) I can't seem to understand how to give priority to the parent or child without using anything but fork() and if.

Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: what is your set-up? Any code of what you have tried already/

Comment: You need some kind of synchronization between the processes, otherwise the order that they run is totally unpredictable.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to synchronize with just the 3 operations you mention.

Comment: Where are the restrictions coming from? Is your question a part of a bigger problem? Are you allowed to use `setpriority()`?

Comment: Is there a requirement that different letters be printed in different processes? What prevents you from printing everything in one process, and doing nothing in the forked child>

Comment: @Barmar Its an exercise that I have to do. Its a simple program that I have to fill the gaps. It starts with "int x,y,z..." (i can declare as many int variables as i want), *big gap*, "printf("A");", *big gap*, printf("B");. I have to fill the gap before the printfA and between the printfA and printfB , so that A is printed 5 times and afterwards B is printed 3 times . But i have to do that by only using fork,if and exit.

Comment: Please put all the requirements in the question, not just a comment.

Comment: @DYZ its just an exercise. a simple program to fill the gaps. all i was given was one "printf("A") and one printf("B"). I need to write code before the printfA and between printfA and printfB so that it prints 5 times "A" and 3 times "B" in the exact same order. I can declare as many int variables as i want, but i cant use anything else but fork, if and exit.

Comment: @Barmar my bad, fixing it rn.

Comment: Fork a process that prints a letter, then it forks a child. Each time you fork, increment a global variable that counts the number of forks. When the number is 1-5, print A. When it's 6-9 print B. When it's higher than that, exit.

Comment: Also make sure you flush after printing each character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are supposed to be learning here is that fork() duplicates your process - at the point of the fork().  It returns a Process IDentifier (PID) **number** to the parent process, and **zero** to the child process.

So by simply watching the return of the fork(), the execution path can determine if they are the parent or child process.

Thus to implement the problem, I took the approach of controlling everything from the single parent process, and having the child simply output a letter, then exit() - which terminates the process.

It would be much nicer with a for() loop, but that was not allowed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0)
        pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0)
        pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0)
        pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0)
        pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // child process only
        printf("A");
        exit(0);
    }

    pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0)
        pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0)
        pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // child process only
        printf("B");
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I *suspect* that it may occasionally get mixed up due to system load, scheduling, etc.  But in all my tests I received the correct answer.

Comment: So let me see if I understand what you did here and correct me if I'm wrong. You forked 5 times and ended up with 5 child processes and 1 parent). Then the 5 child processes had to print "A" and terminate. Then we are back at the start, and you again create 3 child processes that print "B" and terminate. Two question though: 1) when you exit() what processes does it terminate? (I thoiught that exit() terminates the whole program) and 2) in the line where "if(pid==0)" is, why doesn't the counter go to the next 3 forks, therefore printing "B" first?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Jim K - exit() does terminate the process - but since it's inside the (pid == 0) check, only the child process stops.  The parent process has a number for PID (not zero) so does not execute this part.

Comment: @Jim K - follow the process through (in your head) as if you're the parent process.  Each time you call fork(), "pid" will be given the Process ID (PID) of the child.  So using the (pid != 0) check, only the parent process ever calls fork().